# Argument out of range exception to be solved Pls

Tags: c#, exception

I have some code behind and when i run this, an exception pops up. 
I want to fix this. It has been eating my mind. Any help is appreciated.

```
    private void StudentListView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem selectedListViewCell=StudentListView.SelectedItems[0];//
        //problem is about the line above. I have an argument out of range exception  here.
        //it says that InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.
        selectedStudent = (Student)selectedListViewCell.Tag;
        SetDataInTextBoxes();

        selectedRowIndex=StudentListView.SelectedIndices[0];

        SaveButton.Visible = false;
        CancelButton.Visible = false;
        UpdateButton.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling this event handler directly in your code?

Comment: You apparently have no selected items in your listview.

Comment: thats because StudentListView.SelectedItems has no elements inside

Comment: I add elements inside the listview by a button and textboxes already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you don't have any selected item in list view. Make sure that you have first selected any item in your designer. And to avoid exception you should first check then do this

```
ListViewItem selectedListViewCell;
if(StudentListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
     selectedListViewCell=StudentListView.SelectedItems[0];
```

Comment: But it says: "Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement."

Comment: after the if statement

Comment: it's ok but whatever i do, i always have that first exception when i double-click the listview during execution.

Comment: argument out of range exception

Comment: it means that there isn't any selected item in your list view.